# помогите сайт на битриксе перестал работать после обновления

Tags: php, битрикс

помогите сайт на битриксе перестал работать после обновления выдает Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Чего у вас такое в eval() функции выполняется?

Comment: что за eval() я чайник в пхп

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Bitrix\Main\Data\AppCacheManifest' not found in /home/f/firmaacru/incenter/public_html/bitrix/modules/bitrixcloud/classes/general/cdn.php on line 221  очистил кеш браузера скинув кукки сайт для незарегистрированых работает .. но как только пытаешься зайти в админку выскакивает

Comment: Так может этот модуль `bitrix‌​cloud` у вас не совместим с последней версией битрикса? Его тоже стоит обновить наверное. Или отключить пока.

Comment: как обновить? как отключить? могу прислать php код файла cdn.php

Comment: отключил появилась другая ошибка Fatal error: Class 'Bitrix\Main\Page\Frame' not found in /home/f/firmaacru/incenter/public_html/bitrix/modules/aspro.scorp/classes/general/CScorp.php on line 740

Comment: Давайте с другой ошибкой в отдельный вопрос: одна проблема - один топик.